# DatabaseSnapshot executes both if and else

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase for authentication and in the Signup Activity I have something to check if the Username is already taken from a Database that is structured like this:

```
Users
  |
  |
  |
  ----userID
        |-----"username"="exampleusername"
```

My Code recognizes if the username is already taken and returns a Toast Message and doesn't create an user, the problem is if the username isn't taken it also displays this message but the account is created. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private EditText emailTV, passwordTV, usernameTV, fullnameTV;
    private ImageButton regBtn;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private static FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        initializeUI();

        regBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                usernamecheck();
            }
        });
        final TextView signup_button = findViewById(R.id.back_button);
        signup_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }


    private void usernamecheck() {
        String username;
        username = usernameTV.getText().toString();
        DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        ref.orderByChild("username").equalTo(username).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
                if(!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    registerNewUser();
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    userexists();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void userexists(){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.usernameexists), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void registerNewUser() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        String email, password, username, fullname;
        fullname = fullnameTV.getText().toString();
        email = emailTV.getText().toString();
        password = passwordTV.getText().toString();
        username = usernameTV.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(fullname)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.missingfullname), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.missingusername), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.missingmail), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.missingpassword), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return;
        }

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                            String userid = user.getUid();
                            reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userid);

                            HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                            hashMap.put("id", userid);
                            hashMap.put("username", username.toLowerCase());
                            hashMap.put("fullname", fullname);
                            hashMap.put("bio", "");
                            hashMap.put("imageurl", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/frooze-b2248.appspot.com/o/default.png?alt=media&token=aaf52a37-7043-4685-b91f-c6cccda88f4e");
                            reference.setValue(hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                        // Verification Mail
                                        sendVerificationEmail();
                                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        }
                        else {
                            // If registration fails
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.registrationfail), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    public void sendVerificationEmail() {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        // if User logged in
        if (user != null) {
            // Sends verify Mail
            user.sendEmailVerification()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.registrationsuccessful), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

    }
    private void initializeUI() {
        fullnameTV = findViewById(R.id.fullname);
        emailTV = findViewById(R.id.email);
        usernameTV = findViewById(R.id.username);
        passwordTV = findViewById(R.id.password);
        regBtn = findViewById(R.id.register);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `addValueEventListener` and `onDataChange` that means that when a variable is added or changed that listener will be executed. The `addValueEventListener` keeps listening to query or database reference that is attached to.

If you want a single once you must use a different listener. One other listener is `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` that executes the `onDataChange` method once and then it stops listening to the reference that it is attached to.

Comment: Thank you so much!!